# Upgrade Juju from 1.25 to 2.0 ERROR No model in focus

Tags: juju, maas

I have MAAS 1.9 + Juju 1.25 machine running on Ubuntu 14.05 LTS version.

I upgraded OS to 16.04. After upgraded, MAAS working properly. But doesn't work for Juju.

Below is output from Juju 2.0 :

## juju status

```
ERROR No model in focus.

Please use "juju models" to see models available to you.
You can set current model by running "juju switch"
or specify any other model on the command line using the "-m" flag.
```

in Juju-1.25 :

## juju-1.25 status

```
environment: bootstack-preparation
environment-status:
  upgrade-available: 1.25.10
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.6.1
    dns-name: ctr-infra.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-a8589458-e92c-11e6-bde8-44a842430162/
    series: xenial
```

I think all of machines still registered in Juju-1.25. How to migrate them to Juju 2.0 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no upgrade path from Juju 1.25 to Juju 2.0

What happened is that the default Juju executable moved to 2.0 from 1.25.

If you definitely want to use Juju 2.0, you will have to destroy your cloud and controller, and add the MAAS credentials afresh to Juju 2.0.

To stay on 1.25, you'll have to select 1.25 as your default Juju: 
https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.1/juju-coexist

To use Juju 2.0, you'll have to add MAAS credentials to Juju:
https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/clouds-maas.